# Linq List problems checking null

Tags: c#, linq

Given the data below, I am trying to write a LINQ statement that will check if SubscriptionId is null by using `(grp2.Select(y => y.SubscriptionId) == null)`. This must be failing because it will always go into the else section and return `,4` which is not what I am looking for. Is this the correct way to check if this value is null?

LINQPad Example

```
    class Subscription
        {
            public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
            public int ParentProductId { get; set; }
            public string ParentProductName { get; set; }
            public string ChildProductName { get; set; }
            public int ChildProductId { get; set; }
            public int GroupId { get; set; }
            public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        }
        class SubscriptionViewModel
        {
            public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
            public int ParentProductId { get; set; }
            public string ParentProductName { get; set; }
            public string SubscriptionIds { get; set; }
            public int GroupId { get; set; }

        }
        class SubscriptionChildViewModel
        {
            public string ChildProductName { get; set; }
            public int ChildProductId { get; set; }
        }

       

void Main()
{
                List<Subscription> ListOfSubscription = new List<Subscription>();
                ListOfSubscription.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = null, ParentProductId = 4, ChildProductId = 4, ParentProductName = "Product 1", ChildProductName = "Product 1", GroupId = 362, });
        
                ListOfSubscription.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 2, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 1, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 3", GroupId = 1,  });
                ListOfSubscription.Add(new Subscription() { SubscriptionId = 3, ParentProductId = 114, ChildProductId = 2, ParentProductName = "Product 2", ChildProductName = "Product 4", GroupId = 1,   });

                var groupedSubscriptions = ListOfSubscription.GroupBy(u => u.GroupId);

                var result = groupedSubscriptions.Select(grp1 => new
                {
                    GroupId = grp1.Key,
                    Subscriptions = grp1.GroupBy(subscr => new
                    {
                        subscr.ParentProductId,
                        subscr.ParentProductName,
                    })
                    .Select(grp2 => new SubscriptionViewModel
                    {
                        GroupId = grp1.Key,
                        ParentProductId = grp2.Key.ParentProductId,
                        ParentProductName = grp2.Key.ParentProductName,
                        SubscriptionIds = (grp2.Select(y => y.SubscriptionId) == null) ? null : (string.Format("{0},{1}", string.Join(",", grp2.Select(y => y.SubscriptionId)), grp2.Key.ParentProductId))
                })
                });

                var x = result.SelectMany((s => s.Subscriptions));
        
                Console.Write(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic

```cs
(grp2.Select(y => y.SubscriptionId) == null)
```

to

```cs
grp2.Where(y => y.SubscriptionId == null).Count() > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that bracket y.SubscriptionId)

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you, to work with nulleables you can use "HasValue" instead of directly comparing with null.

SubscriptionIds = (grp2.Select(  y => y.SubscriptionId.HasValue  ) == null) ? null : (string.Format("{0},{1}", string.Join(",", grp2.Select(y => y.SubscriptionId.HasValue)), grp2.Key.ParentProductId))

Microsoft suggests using HasValue for nulleables types